# Get all values using list iterator

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm trying to write command line parser. Here is example of code that i used to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<std::string> args;
    args.push_back("-l");
    args.push_back("-z");
    args.push_back("123,abc");
    args.push_back("-d");
    args.push_back("/dev/null");

    std::list<std::string>::iterator currentArgument;

    for (currentArgument = args.begin(); currentArgument != args.end();) {
        const std::string argString = *currentArgument++;
        if (argString.at(0) == '-') {
                std::cout << "key = " << argString.substr(1) << std::endl;
                std::cout << "value = " << *currentArgument << std::endl;
            } else {
                --currentArgument;
                break;
            }
        }
};
```

Result is:

```
key = l
value = -z
key = z
value = 123,abc
```

I tried to rewrite source code as in the example in Java:
[Args.java](https://www.javatips.net/api/javaargs-master/src/com/cleancoder/args/Args.java) (parseArgumentStrings method)

The problem is bool -l key, it has no value and i don't need to modify args list by adding "1" after -l or something. I can't get last key and value because argString is "123,abc" at that moment. If you look on source Java code it has hasNext() member function

So, how to rewrite this code and get output like this:

```
key = l
value = -z
key = z
value = 123,abc
key = d
value = /dev/null
```

Comment: Why `--args.end()` in `currentArgument != --args.end()` instead of simply `args.end()`? Is it a typo?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, yes it must be just `args.end()`

Comment: `key = l; value = -z` Are you sure this is the desired behavior instead of something like an empty string?  I guess you could argue that the value of a boolean flag is meaningless, but seems like that would be confusing to whoever is using this parser.

Comment: @Anzipex 1) So, it's unclear what is unclear to you. You wrote the code, which breaks out of the loop if the condition `if (argString.at(0) == '-')` is false. Which is the case when `argString == "123,abc"`. 2) When the code doesn't do what you expect, the typical thing to do is: stepping through the code with a debugger, while investigating the values of variables at each execution step. Did you  try doing it?

Comment: And why not hold off the `currentArgument++` part until you know that the argument starts with `-`? That way you don't have to decrease the iterator in the `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments already, it's a bit confusing why boolean flag would have next flag as value. You did not either mention about which C++ standard/version you are using.

I now assume your question is what's wrong with the algorithm?

- Firs of all, the break statement jumps out of the for-loop (basic stuff)
- without the break, it'll printout the last argument also, but it'll also stay in forever loop (since first incrementing pointer and then decrementing it)

As stated in comments also, it would be better to check first for the '-' before 
incrementing the pointer. Note also that there exist a std::next which can be used here.

I'm not sure either that list (internally a double linked list) is best container here.

If we assume that the boolean flag should not have a value printed out, the code could look like this:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> args;
    args.push_back("-l");
    args.push_back("-z");
    args.push_back("123,abc");
    args.push_back("-d");
    args.push_back("/dev/null");

    for (auto it = std::begin(args); it != std::end(args); ++it) {
        if ((*it).at(0) == '-') {
            std::cout << "key = " << (*it).substr(1) << std::endl;
            auto next = std::next(it);
            if ((*next).at(0) == '-'){
                continue;
            }else{
                std::cout << "value = " << *(++it) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course that code does not take into account the possibility of last argument to be value only (no flag). But that's easy to implement, if needed.

I hope this helps, but I encourage you to also learn how to debug code:

- debugger, has some learning curve but it is worth it
- simple cout's

Comment: I'm using C ++11. I see that this code really simplifies the solution